# Recordings of New Year celebrations!

Tags: field-recording

I've just done some recordings of the fireworks at midnight here in Tallinn (I will be putting  the sounds online later, and will update this post with the links)

Has anyone else made any recordings of the celebrations, would be interested to hear the different sounds of the start of 2012.

Wishing you all a fantastic 2012.

- Midnight fireworks no.1 (Rode NTG3 into Sound Devices 744): [link text](http://soundcloud.com/siaudio/atm_fireworks_newyear_2012)
- Midnight fireworks no.2 (Sony PCM D-50): [link text](http://soundcloud.com/siaudio/atm_fireworks_newyear_2012_02)
- Midnight fireworks no.2 (Sony PCM D-50): [link text](http://soundcloud.com/siaudio/atm_fireworks_newyear_2012_03--)

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you guys could contribute these sounds to the Designing Sound/Sonic-Terrain Sonic-Mash! http://bit.ly/sQmbXA

Have a great year ahead!

Answer (score 1):

Made 40 minutes of fireworks/bells @ this little quiet village on The Alps: Maishofen Salzburg, Austria.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few minutes from the centre of Rotterdam, the Netherlands:

http://soundcloud.com/jorgschellekens/nye-2012-field-recording

Nothing too fancy, just a Zoom H2 out of the window of my appartement on the 5th floor.

Happy new year to all!

Answer (score 1):

I recorded about 20 minutes of material. While my friends were celebrating at midnight I had gone out on a field about 150 metres to get away from the voices. Here's about 01:20:

- [Fireworks Ambience](http://audiojungle.net/item/fireworks-ambience/1265385?ref=Reachground)

When I got back to my friends there was a family shooting rockets from a parking lot. I got close and this is one of the many:

- [Single Rocket Launch](http://audiojungle.net/item/fireworks-single-rocket-launch/1217652?ref=Reachground)

Comment: Damnit, I didn't look at the date. Can't even rember how I found the thread :)

Comment: No problem, it's nice to have people responding to posts a while after they were posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just pressed stop on my recorder. Having 45 mins of absolute madness to edit in the coming days. 
Dpa 4061 low sens, handled the boooms nicely, and was easy to strap just outside the window.

Happy new year all. 
      [HappyNewYear2012 DPA4061Sounddevices702](http://soundcloud.com/gimaudio/happynewyear2012) by [gimaudio](http://soundcloud.com/gimaudio)

Answer (score 0):

I have 45 mins of stuff as well... But here in the Philippines, you get a lot of karaoke going on everywhere. But I'm sure there's a lot of good stuff I can get after editing through it.

Recorded M/S with a Sanken CMS-7s @ 192khz.

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Nice tread ;) i made also a 50 minute recording. Here's a link of a short edit...
I used a nt4 into my h4n

http://www.klang-manufaktur.de/free-sound-of-the-day